# SQL Update after INNER JOIN two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like `Update` two tables on the same `Update` statement with `INNER JOIN` but I cant attach second table

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.status='test1', T2.status='test1' 
FROM mytable1 T1 
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.id 
WHERE parameters.....
```

But I cant use `T2.status='test1'` 
error I am getting

> The multi-part identifier "T2.status" could not be bound.

Comment: In SQL Server, you can only update one table at a time using `update`.

Comment: Check your Update statement, it says Update Tablename Set ..... which means only one table is allowed to get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update 2 tables in a single update statement, even if using join clause. The join clause can be used for "filtering" purposes only. Only FROM table can be updated.